# Вылетает ошибка "Undefined reference to..." (СodeBlocks 20.02, язык C)

Tags: c, codeblocks

Недавно начал работать на CodeBlocks (20.03) и решать простенькие задачи (язык C).
Однако в ходе решения одной из таких задач столкнулся с проблемой:

```
int main(void)
{int a,b,c,d,e;
scanf("%d%d%d%d%d",&a,&b,&c,&d,&e);
printf("Maximum is: %d\n", maximum(a,b,c,d,e));
return 0;

undefined reference to 'maximum'
```

Как я понимаю, проблема заключается в том, у меня не установлена библиотека Math, в которой и содержится функция max. В связи с этим вопросом: надо ли устанавливать эту библиотеку? И если да, то как именно (хотелось бы услышать подробный перечень шагов)?
P.S. Если я уж где-то дико туплю, то заранее прошу прошения.

Comment: IMHO такой стандарной для С функции нет (также как и max/MAX) Если вам нужна такая функция, то сами ее и напишите. Впрочем, можно подсмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3437404/7286264)

Comment: *"содержится функция max"* - но вы же ее не вызываете, у вас - `maximum`.